# FutureWarning when comparing a NumPy object to "None"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function that receives some arguments, plus some optional arguments. In it, the action taken is dependent upon whether the optional argument `c` was filled:

```
def func(a, b, c = None):

    doStuff()

    if c != None:
        doOtherStuff()
```

If `c` is not passed, then this works fine. However, in my context, if `c` *is* passed, it will always be a `numpy` array. And comparing `numpy` arrays to `None` yields the following warning:

```
FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
```

So, what is the cleanest and most general way to check whether or not `c` was passed or not without comparing to `None`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `if c is not None` instead. In addition to avoiding the warning, this is [generally considered best-practice](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Comment: Just noting that in the original context, `if c is not None:` is appropriate.